# Connecting 4TB NAS Hard Drive to RPi 4B

Tags: networking, pi-4, hard-drive, storage

I have currently set up a NAS using a 2TB external USB hard drive on my RPi 4b using Samba.
The problem is my HDD is now slow and doesn't provide enough speed for my plex media server direct stream to my media station.

So I planned to upgrade to a NAS drive as serves my needs well and has 200mbps read and write which is more than sufficient for my use case and I don't need much Random IO speed on the disk.

Upon reading, I came across the problem that Pi won't be able to single-handedly power up the HDD, and in some cases, it kills the Pi too. So how I see this is I would need to power up the HDD using the PC PSU and have a SATA3 to USB adapter for the HDD. Is there a way I can bulk down the PSU to a smaller size PSU only for HDD?  because I can't have a big-sized PSU where the pi lives right now.

TO Summarise,

1. Can I use a 4Tb IronWolf NAS HDD with Pi using an external Power adapter solution, If Yes, Please Suggest.
2. I am getting this HDD plus adapter for 135 to 140 USD,( I live in India so I have converted it to USD for Simplicity ) is there a better or easier solution.

Comment: `my HDD is now slow...` - If your HDD was fast, but has slowed since you began using `plex`, you should know that Ethernet and USB share a single "pipeline". When you're trying to pull your data in from the HDD, and push it out over the network, you may be hitting the bandwidth limit on the internal USB pipeline.

Comment: I never had crazy good performance, it has always been 20 mbps on this external hard drive even when connected directly to my pc.